# Rauchen, brauchen, what is the exact phonetic difference between the "r" and "ch" sounds in these words, if there is any?

Tags: pronunciation

I have noticed that in some accents the "r" sound is more trilled. But does this happen in every accent?

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fl8ECMCOjzI) I cannot tell any difference between the two.

Comment: I guess it depends on the dialect. In *Hochdeutsch* there is no difference.

Comment: The difference is simple: "r" is voiced, "ch" is unvoiced. The differences between "r" sounds in different words is much more subtle and subject to dialects and ideolects.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between **rauchen** and **brauchen** is the **r** is at the beginning of the syllable in *rauchen*. If so, it has to make a sound. There aren't any silent sounds in German pronounciation.

In *brauchen* however, the **r** can become almost silent, a lot of speakers will simple aspirate it, making it sound as *ch*. Other speakers use the same *r* as at the beginning of a syllable.

It's more a matter of personal preference than of dialect, but southern speakers may even roll the **r**.

Comment: The /r/ cannot become silent in the word *brauchen.* Otherwise, it would sound like *Bauch,* which it certainly does not.

Comment: That's why I wrote **almost**.